# sIFR jQuery toggle, not working in FF3

Tags: jquery, firefox, sifr

I have a sIFR replaced H2 link that simply toggles (w/ jQuery) another div on and off. 'Seems' to work in all browsers but Firefox 3. Any thoughts ?

```
<ul id="titlenav">
   <li><h2><a href="javascript:void()">Title</a></h2>
    <ul id="titlemenu">
       <li>1</li>
       <li>2</li>
       <li>3</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>


$('#titlenav h2').click(function() {
  $('#titlemenu').Toggle();
});
```

My siFr replace config and css is ultra simple and sIFr links generally work, just not jquery functions. Im using ;
- jquery-1.3.1
- sIFR 3 R 427

Any advice welcomed. I'm pretty new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the click event on the Flash doesn't propagate to the `h2` element. Check out the [`onRelease` callback](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript+Methods), which you can specify as an argument to `sIFR.replace`. It's fired whenever you click on a replaced Flash movie.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? I've heard there are problems getting sFIR to run correctly with alpha transparency on linux systems; it could be the cause.

If you're still having problems with this an alternative may be [typeface.js](http://typeface.neocracy.org/) which is all js, no flash.

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows (XP) or Mac OSX (Leopard). I'm not using transperency either. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've never heard about this sIFR thingy before.  Looks cool, though, that is, when I can get it to work. Apparently, most of the sIFR demos I found fail to work with FF3 on Ubuntu Linux. Finally, I found one which works, and also offers jQuery integration: http://dev.jquery.com/~gilles/sifr/, you might want to check it out.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking of looking into that (or one like it), though, I I've gotten this far with sIFR and all I need is for it to trigger jquery. Doesn't seem I'm that far away. Maybe.