# Calling javascript from sifr replaced anchor tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, sifr, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm using sIFR to replace my navigation text with a new font:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">reel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">archive</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">login</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

```
sIFR.replace(futura, {
    css: [
        '.sIFR-root { background-color:transparent; color: #999999; cursor:pointer; font-size:26px; text-transform:uppercase; }',
        'a { color: #999999; text-decoration:none; }',
        'a:hover { color: #CCCCCC; text-decoration:none; }'
    ],
    fitExactly:true,
    forceClear:true,
    forceSingleLine:true,
    selector: '#navigation ul li',
    transparent:true
});
```

That works just fine. I'm then trying to add some actions to the navigation using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation ul li a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("nav clicked");
    });
});
```

These actions don't seem to be working though because the anchor tags are hidden by sIFR when the content is replaced. How does one add some jQuery code to replaced tags? I'd rather not do something like the following (and let javascript be called from Flash) as it sort of defeats the whole purpose of unobtrusive javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:gotoSection('about');">about</a>
```

---

**Edit (generated HTML)**:

```
<ul>
    <li style="" class="sIFR-replaced"><object width="88" height="37" class="sIFR-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="sIFR_replacement_0" name="sIFR_replacement_0" data="/swf/bfuturah.swf" style=""><param name="flashvars" value="id=sIFR_replacement_0&amp;content=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522/home/about%2522%2520target%253D%2522%2522%253EABOUT%253C/a%253E&amp;width=55&amp;renderheight=37&amp;link=/home/about&amp;target=&amp;size=26&amp;css=.sIFR-root%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253B%257Da%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257Da%253Ahover%257Bcolor%253A%2523CCCCCC%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257D&amp;cursor=pointer&amp;tunewidth=0&amp;tuneheight=0&amp;offsetleft=&amp;offsettop=&amp;fitexactly=true&amp;preventwrap=false&amp;forcesingleline=true&amp;antialiastype=&amp;thickness=&amp;sharpness=&amp;kerning=&amp;gridfittype=pixel&amp;flashfilters=&amp;opacity=100&amp;blendmode=&amp;selectable=true&amp;fixhover=true&amp;events=false&amp;delayrun=false&amp;version=436"/><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="bgcolor" value="transparent"/><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/><param name="quality" value="best"/></object><span class="sIFR-alternate" id="sIFR_replacement_0_alternate"><a href="/home/about">about</a></span></li>
    <li style="" class="sIFR-replaced"><object width="58" height="37" class="sIFR-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="sIFR_replacement_1" name="sIFR_replacement_1" data="/swf/bfuturah.swf" style=""><param name="flashvars" value="id=sIFR_replacement_1&amp;content=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522/home/reel%2522%2520target%253D%2522%2522%253EREEL%253C/a%253E&amp;width=42&amp;renderheight=37&amp;link=/home/reel&amp;target=&amp;size=26&amp;css=.sIFR-root%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253B%257Da%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257Da%253Ahover%257Bcolor%253A%2523CCCCCC%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257D&amp;cursor=pointer&amp;tunewidth=0&amp;tuneheight=0&amp;offsetleft=&amp;offsettop=&amp;fitexactly=true&amp;preventwrap=false&amp;forcesingleline=true&amp;antialiastype=&amp;thickness=&amp;sharpness=&amp;kerning=&amp;gridfittype=pixel&amp;flashfilters=&amp;opacity=100&amp;blendmode=&amp;selectable=true&amp;fixhover=true&amp;events=false&amp;delayrun=false&amp;version=436"/><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="bgcolor" value="transparent"/><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/><param name="quality" value="best"/></object><span class="sIFR-alternate" id="sIFR_replacement_1_alternate"><a href="/home/reel">reel</a></span></li>
    <li style="" class="sIFR-replaced"><object width="116" height="37" class="sIFR-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="sIFR_replacement_2" name="sIFR_replacement_2" data="/swf/bfuturah.swf" style=""><param name="flashvars" value="id=sIFR_replacement_2&amp;content=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522/home/contact%2522%2520target%253D%2522%2522%253ECONTACT%253C/a%253E&amp;width=76&amp;renderheight=37&amp;link=/home/contact&amp;target=&amp;size=26&amp;css=.sIFR-root%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253B%257Da%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257Da%253Ahover%257Bcolor%253A%2523CCCCCC%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257D&amp;cursor=pointer&amp;tunewidth=0&amp;tuneheight=0&amp;offsetleft=&amp;offsettop=&amp;fitexactly=true&amp;preventwrap=false&amp;forcesingleline=true&amp;antialiastype=&amp;thickness=&amp;sharpness=&amp;kerning=&amp;gridfittype=pixel&amp;flashfilters=&amp;opacity=100&amp;blendmode=&amp;selectable=true&amp;fixhover=true&amp;events=false&amp;delayrun=false&amp;version=436"/><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="bgcolor" value="transparent"/><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/><param name="quality" value="best"/></object><span class="sIFR-alternate" id="sIFR_replacement_2_alternate"><a href="/home/contact">contact</a></span></li>
    <li style="" class="sIFR-replaced"><object width="110" height="37" class="sIFR-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="sIFR_replacement_3" name="sIFR_replacement_3" data="/swf/bfuturah.swf" style=""><param name="flashvars" value="id=sIFR_replacement_3&amp;content=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522/archive%2522%2520target%253D%2522%2522%253EARCHIVE%253C/a%253E&amp;width=72&amp;renderheight=37&amp;link=/archive&amp;target=&amp;size=26&amp;css=.sIFR-root%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253B%257Da%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257Da%253Ahover%257Bcolor%253A%2523CCCCCC%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257D&amp;cursor=pointer&amp;tunewidth=0&amp;tuneheight=0&amp;offsetleft=&amp;offsettop=&amp;fitexactly=true&amp;preventwrap=false&amp;forcesingleline=true&amp;antialiastype=&amp;thickness=&amp;sharpness=&amp;kerning=&amp;gridfittype=pixel&amp;flashfilters=&amp;opacity=100&amp;blendmode=&amp;selectable=true&amp;fixhover=true&amp;events=false&amp;delayrun=false&amp;version=436"/><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="bgcolor" value="transparent"/><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/><param name="quality" value="best"/></object><span class="sIFR-alternate" id="sIFR_replacement_3_alternate"><a href="/archive">archive</a></span></li>
<a href="/archive">    </a><li style="" class="sIFR-replaced"><object width="80" height="37" class="sIFR-flash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="sIFR_replacement_4" name="sIFR_replacement_4" data="/swf/bfuturah.swf" style=""><param name="flashvars" value="id=sIFR_replacement_4&amp;content=%253Ca%2520href%253D%2522/login%2522%2520target%253D%2522%2522%253ELOGIN%253C/a%253E&amp;width=50&amp;renderheight=37&amp;link=/login&amp;target=&amp;size=26&amp;css=.sIFR-root%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253B%257Da%257Bcolor%253A%2523999999%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257Da%253Ahover%257Bcolor%253A%2523CCCCCC%253Btext-decoration%253Anone%253B%257D&amp;cursor=pointer&amp;tunewidth=0&amp;tuneheight=0&amp;offsetleft=&amp;offsettop=&amp;fitexactly=true&amp;preventwrap=false&amp;forcesingleline=true&amp;antialiastype=&amp;thickness=&amp;sharpness=&amp;kerning=&amp;gridfittype=pixel&amp;flashfilters=&amp;opacity=100&amp;blendmode=&amp;selectable=true&amp;fixhover=true&amp;events=false&amp;delayrun=false&amp;version=436"/><param name="wmode" value="transparent"/><param name="bgcolor" value="transparent"/><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"/><param name="quality" value="best"/></object><span class="sIFR-alternate" id="sIFR_replacement_4_alternate"><a href="/login">login</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [626595](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626595/sifr-jquery-toggle-not-working-in-ff3) and [801642](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801642/onclick-event-on-sifr-embed-tag-in-ie), the click event doesn't get propagated out. If you're using sIFR 3, there's an [onRelease](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript%2BMethods) callback you can pass into `sIFR.replace()`, which gets given a [FlashInteractor](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/FlashInteractor) object. From there you can use `getAncestor()` to get access to the replaced element.

So, your code will probably look something like the following. *(this is untested by me)*

```
sIFR.replace(futura, {
    /* the rest of your replace params */
    selector: '#navigation ul li',
    transparent:true,
    onRelease: function(fi) { liClick( fi.getAncestor() ); }
});

function liClick(li) {
    var $li = $(li),
        $a = $(li).find('a');
    //$li points at a jQuery'd list item
    //$a points at the original anchor
}
```

Mark Wubben's [answer](http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=195419#p195419) in [this](http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=22375) forum post was very enlightening for `getAncestor` and `onRelease`

Comment: Nice! That helps a lot. Is there a way to cancel the default action of the anchor tag then (event.preventDefault or return false) in this context?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure, I've not used sIFR with links before. There's a couple of handy looking callbacks at http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript%2BMethods - modifyContentString or modifyContent could probably be used to replace the links with spans before sIFR uses them, that way they'll not end up as navigation elements in the movie. It's worth a shot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the .live method? [Live method docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn)

```
$("#navigation ul li a").live('click', function(e){
//Code here
});
```

It may be a case of hacking around a little, maybe adding the events to the .sifr-replaced elements. I haven't used sifr in a while so my memory is a little rusty on what it inserts.

Maybe post a sample of the generated HTML.

Hope that helps.